# Generate diagram from SQL script in MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Is there any possibility to create visual diagram from SQL script?
I've my DB saved in MySQL on Localhost. And I want to visualize it. If this program cannot do that and you know about another, please tell me.

Thanks a lot;

Answer (score 14):

In the latest MWB 6.3 version you need to do the following

1) On the home page click on  the ">" sign just below the label `Models` 
2) It will show you to create EER diagram from either Database or SQL files

[image: generate EER from DB or SQL Script]

Answer (score 4):

I have found answer here on official program website: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-create-script.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use MySQL Workbench modeller